# An easy rebus y'all!

Tags: visual, rebus

This rebus expresses a simple phrase. What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the phrase is

> [Oil and water do not mix](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/oil+and+water+do+not+mix)

Reasoning

> The string of characters HIJKLMNO is sometimes used as a pun to refer to water because it is the letters "H to O" (sounds like H2O) and it seems as though the letters O,I,L are separating from this string, that is, the OIL is not mixing in the water.

Comment: And there was me looking for something involving gamma decay on every third letter ...